# detect mouse position and if it collides with object display text

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to display some text every time the mouse collides with the animating svg, when the mouse isn't over the svg i don't want the text to display , i made a codepen if anyone could help me. Thank you :) 
https://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/mBOPzR

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var fly = document.getElementById('fly');
var text = document.getElementById('text');



var angleX = 0;
var angleY = 0;
var range = 100;
var xspeed = 0.06;
var yspeed = 0.08;

var transY = 0;
var transX = 0;

var flyPos;

function drawFrame() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
 transX = Math.sin(angleX) * range;
 transY = Math.sin(angleY) * range;
 fly.style.transform = `translate3d(${transX}px,${transY}px,0)`
 angleX += xspeed;
 angleY += yspeed;
 flyPos = fly.getBoundingClientRect();
}


 fly.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;

 /* if the mouse x position collides with the fly i want to display the 
 message */
  if (x > flyPos.left && x < flyPos.right || y > flyPos.top && y < 
   flyPos.bottom) {

    text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
    }
 });


window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Record your mouse position changes in your mousemove handler.  Then move your collision test to the `drawFrame()` function, so it gets tested every time the fly moves.

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  ...

  /* if the mouse x position collides with the fly i want to display the message */
  flyPos = fly.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (mouseX > flyPos.left && mouseX < flyPos.right && mouseY > flyPos.top && mouseY < flyPos.bottom) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

...

svgContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});
```

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var fly = document.getElementById('fly');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-container');



var angleX = 0;
var angleY = 0;
var range = 100;
var xspeed = 0.06;
var yspeed = 0.08;

var transY = 0;
var transX = 0;

var flyPos;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  transX = Math.sin(angleX) * range;
  transY = Math.sin(angleY) * range;
  fly.style.transform = `translate3d(${transX}px,${transY}px,0)`
  angleX += xspeed;
  angleY += yspeed;

  /* if the mouse x position collides with the fly i want to display the message */
  flyPos = fly.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (mouseX > flyPos.left && mouseX < flyPos.right && mouseY > flyPos.top && mouseY < flyPos.bottom) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

svgContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 cursor:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'),auto;

}

.svg-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#svg { 
  width: 7em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8em;
  margin: auto;
}


#back_wing {
  animation: backwing .2s linear reverse infinite;
}

#forward_wing {
  animation: frontwing .2s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes backwing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(12deg);
  }
  
}

@keyframes frontwing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#text {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Flies have feelings </h1>

<div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">

<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165.32 126.08"><defs><style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2{fill:#f4f4f4;}.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-2,.cls-5,.cls-7{stroke:#000;}.cls-10,.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-13,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-19,.cls-2,.cls-3,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-18,.cls-19,.cls-3,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7{fill:none;}.cls-3,.cls-4{stroke:#73e4ef;}.cls-10,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-3,.cls-6{stroke-width:0.25px;}.cls-5{stroke-width:2px;}.cls-6{stroke:#189cb2;}.cls-12,.cls-17,.cls-8{fill:#4d727b;}.cls-9{fill:#d40000;}.cls-10{fill:#5a9761;}.cls-10,.cls-13,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-19{stroke:#000202;}.cls-11{fill:#0b8e9b;}.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-13{stroke-width:0.5px;}.cls-13{fill:#3d595e;}.cls-14{fill:#0f1c59;opacity:0.4;mix-blend-mode:multiply;}.cls-15,.cls-16{fill:#f2f970;}.cls-16{opacity:0.5;mix-blend-mode:overlay;}.cls-19{stroke-width:0.75px;}.cls-20{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>fly</title><g id="fly" class="cls-1"><g id="back_wing"><path class="cls-2" d="M94.49 57.12s14.44-78 39-50.92-33 49.66-33 49.66z"/><g id="back_wing_pattern"><path class="cls-3" d="M113.33 49.67l-12.41-17.56M117.06 2.74l-8.77 39.81M113.33 22.65l23.93 6.16"/></g></g><g id="legs"><path class="cls-5" d="M105.73 105.18l-9.79 9.21 3.94 11.36"/><path class="cls-5" d="M114.69 121.74l-11.63-11.75 7.82-13.71 17.9 3.66 6.98 20.26"/><path class="cls-5" d="M110.21 100.47l14.34 5.82 4.74 10.98"/></g><g id="forward_wing"><path class="cls-2" d="M97.31 64.03S53.63 11.71 23.67 11.39s-32 38.31.4 46 66.74 8.92 66.74 8.92z"/><g id="forward_wing_pattern"><path class="cls-3" d="M61.82 63.86l10.39-25.59M17.79 11.89l16.14 47.62M19.12 15.83l45.44 41.29"/></g></g><g id="body"><path class="cls-8" d="M156.12 79.68a30.58 30.58 0 0 1-23.22 11.85h-2.76l-5.3-6.38c2.47-3.76 3.52-9.29 2.71-15.25a31.51 31.51 0 0 0-.84-4.06c-3-10.85-11.12-18.14-18.42-16.69a30.85 30.85 0 0 1 22.23-10.62 32.18 32.18 0 0 1 11.86 1.67c-5.88 3.41-8.42 13-5.67 23 3.08 11.18 11.62 18.58 19.08 16.53z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M163.71 55.81c3 11-.37 21.59-7.59 23.87l-.33.1c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-2.75-10-.21-19.61 5.67-23a9.33 9.33 0 0 1 2.25-1c7.46-2.02 16 5.38 19.08 16.56z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M124.84 85.13l5.3 6.38a31.52 31.52 0 0 1-10.26-2.11 11 11 0 0 0 4.96-4.27z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M127.55 69.88c.81 6-.24 11.49-2.71 15.25l-24.33-29.27c1.55-3.32 4-5.71 7.12-6.58l.66-.16c7.3-1.45 15.43 5.84 18.42 16.69a31.51 31.51 0 0 1 .84 4.06z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M100.51 55.86l24.33 29.27a11 11 0 0 1-5 4.27 8.27 8.27 0 0 1-1.09.38c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-1.79-6.48-1.34-12.81.79-17.39z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M119.88 89.4a31.52 31.52 0 0 0 10.26 2.13 28.08 28.08 0 0 1-10.26 14.78 27.86 27.86 0 0 1-16.66 5.5L79.04 69.53a28 28 0 0 1 21.46-13.67c-2.13 4.58-2.58 10.91-.79 17.39 3.08 11.18 11.62 18.58 19.08 16.53a8.27 8.27 0 0 0 1.09-.38zM79.04 69.53l24.17 42.27a28 28 0 0 1-24.17-42.27z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M103.21 111.8s-22.55 1.78-42.87-5.51 18.7-36.76 18.7-36.76a28 28 0 0 0 24.17 42.27z"/><path class="cls-7" d="M79.04 69.53s-39 29.47-18.71 36.76 42.88 5.51 42.88 5.51M119.88 106.29a28.08 28.08 0 0 0 10.26-14.76M100.5 55.86a28 28 0 1 0 19.36 50.44M119.88 89.4a31.52 31.52 0 0 0 10.26 2.13h2.76a30.58 30.58 0 0 0 23.22-11.82M108.29 49.12a30.85 30.85 0 0 1 22.23-10.59 32.18 32.18 0 0 1 11.86 1.67M119.88 106.29"/><path class="cls-7" d="M127.55 69.88c.81 6-.24 11.49-2.71 15.25a11 11 0 0 1-5 4.27 8.27 8.27 0 0 1-1.09.38c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-1.79-6.48-1.34-12.81.79-17.39 1.55-3.32 4-5.71 7.12-6.58l.66-.16c7.3-1.45 15.43 5.84 18.42 16.69a31.51 31.51 0 0 1 .84 4.06M142.38 40.23a9.33 9.33 0 0 1 2.25-1c7.46-2 16 5.35 19.08 16.53 3 11-.37 21.59-7.59 23.87l-.33.1c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-2.75-9.93-.21-19.56 5.67-22.97zM127.55 69.88"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="121.08" cy="97.99" r="1.21"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="121.68" cy="94.89" r=".61"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="123.98" cy="95.89" r=".39"/></g><g id="nose"><path class="cls-12" d="M158.21 88.14s-15-7.48-14.14-8.46-1.66 1.52-1.66 1.52c4 .33 11.67 12.18 11.67 12.18"/><ellipse class="cls-13" cx="292.91" cy="122.23" rx="3.34" ry="1.89" transform="rotate(-51.71 192.082 247.63)"/></g><g id="shadows"><path class="cls-14" d="M119.88 89.4s-34.89-1.12-38.22 12.32c0 0 12.9 17.58 37.35 5.2 0 0 10.56-9.67 11.13-15.4 0 .01-10.93-.87-10.26-2.12z"/><path class="cls-14" d="M81.66 101.72s-31.43 1.67-21.34 4.57 32.93 7.11 37 5.51c-.01 0-15.29-6.73-15.66-10.08z"/></g><g id="lights"><path class="cls-16" d="M128.98 38.85s-15 1-20.69 10.27c0 0 15.28-10.05 20.69-10.27zM100.5 55.86S83.77 57.3 76.21 76.04c0 0 13.58-16.85 24.29-20.18zM78.58 69.88S57.78 87 56.14 93.53"/></g><g id="hair"><path class="cls-17" d="M134.75 117.27l1.01-3.74M133.46 113.53l-3.32-1.54M131.85 108.87l1.61-2.58"/><path class="cls-18" d="M112.68 119.71l.53-2.44M107.12 117.27h3.09v-3.74M127.55 115.4h-2.21M126.45 110.67l1.1-3.09M99.27 124.01l1.65-2.27M94.49 119.71h2.83M96.94 117.27l2.33-1.87"/><path class="cls-19" d="M113.32 36.79c9.36-2.93 13.12 8.68 13.12 8.68M127 42.55l-.55-6.85"/></g><g id="eyes"><ellipse cx="253.34" cy="111.51" rx="8.43" ry="10.34" transform="rotate(-22.59 106.112 438.183)"/><ellipse cx="290.34" cy="101" rx="8.43" ry="10.34" transform="rotate(-22.59 143.093 427.685)"/><ellipse class="cls-20" cx="256.2" cy="105.15" rx="1.31" ry="2.26" transform="rotate(-45 149.82 254.532)"/><ellipse class="cls-20" cx="293.63" cy="94.75" rx="1.31" ry="2.26" transform="rotate(-45 187.25 244.128)"/><circle class="cls-20" cx="118.24" cy="75.68" r=".4"/><circle class="cls-20" cx="156.12" cy="65.55" r=".4"/></g></g></svg>

<div id="text">
  <h1> ouch </h1>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think elementFromPoint is what you're really looking for isn't it? This will return what the mouse is over. At the moment you're matching on the entire bounding box including parts where the fly is not drawn.

As for the rest I've incorporated Paul LeBau's fixes in my answer. I.e check for collision in the drawFrame.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var fly = document.getElementById('fly');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-container');



var angleX = 0;
var angleY = 0;
var range = 100;
var xspeed = 0.06;
var yspeed = 0.08;

var transY = 0;
var transX = 0;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function drawFrame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  transX = Math.sin(angleX) * range;
  transY = Math.sin(angleY) * range;
  fly.style.transform = `translate3d(${transX}px,${transY}px,0)`
  angleX += xspeed;
  angleY += yspeed;

  /* if the mouse x position collides with the fly i want to display the message */
  var e = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
  if (e instanceof SVGElement && !(e instanceof SVGSVGElement)) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

svgContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 cursor:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'),auto;

}

.svg-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#svg { 
  width: 7em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8em;
  margin: auto;
}


#back_wing {
  animation: backwing .2s linear reverse infinite;
}

#forward_wing {
  animation: frontwing .2s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes backwing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(12deg);
  }
  
}

@keyframes frontwing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#text {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Flies have feelings </h1>

<div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">

<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165.32 126.08"><defs><style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2{fill:#f4f4f4;}.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-2,.cls-5,.cls-7{stroke:#000;}.cls-10,.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-13,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-19,.cls-2,.cls-3,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-18,.cls-19,.cls-3,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7{fill:none;}.cls-3,.cls-4{stroke:#73e4ef;}.cls-10,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-3,.cls-6{stroke-width:0.25px;}.cls-5{stroke-width:2px;}.cls-6{stroke:#189cb2;}.cls-12,.cls-17,.cls-8{fill:#4d727b;}.cls-9{fill:#d40000;}.cls-10{fill:#5a9761;}.cls-10,.cls-13,.cls-17,.cls-18,.cls-19{stroke:#000202;}.cls-11{fill:#0b8e9b;}.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-13{stroke-width:0.5px;}.cls-13{fill:#3d595e;}.cls-14{fill:#0f1c59;opacity:0.4;mix-blend-mode:multiply;}.cls-15,.cls-16{fill:#f2f970;}.cls-16{opacity:0.5;mix-blend-mode:overlay;}.cls-19{stroke-width:0.75px;}.cls-20{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>fly</title><g id="fly" class="cls-1"><g id="back_wing"><path class="cls-2" d="M94.49 57.12s14.44-78 39-50.92-33 49.66-33 49.66z"/><g id="back_wing_pattern"><path class="cls-3" d="M113.33 49.67l-12.41-17.56M117.06 2.74l-8.77 39.81M113.33 22.65l23.93 6.16"/></g></g><g id="legs"><path class="cls-5" d="M105.73 105.18l-9.79 9.21 3.94 11.36"/><path class="cls-5" d="M114.69 121.74l-11.63-11.75 7.82-13.71 17.9 3.66 6.98 20.26"/><path class="cls-5" d="M110.21 100.47l14.34 5.82 4.74 10.98"/></g><g id="forward_wing"><path class="cls-2" d="M97.31 64.03S53.63 11.71 23.67 11.39s-32 38.31.4 46 66.74 8.92 66.74 8.92z"/><g id="forward_wing_pattern"><path class="cls-3" d="M61.82 63.86l10.39-25.59M17.79 11.89l16.14 47.62M19.12 15.83l45.44 41.29"/></g></g><g id="body"><path class="cls-8" d="M156.12 79.68a30.58 30.58 0 0 1-23.22 11.85h-2.76l-5.3-6.38c2.47-3.76 3.52-9.29 2.71-15.25a31.51 31.51 0 0 0-.84-4.06c-3-10.85-11.12-18.14-18.42-16.69a30.85 30.85 0 0 1 22.23-10.62 32.18 32.18 0 0 1 11.86 1.67c-5.88 3.41-8.42 13-5.67 23 3.08 11.18 11.62 18.58 19.08 16.53z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M163.71 55.81c3 11-.37 21.59-7.59 23.87l-.33.1c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-2.75-10-.21-19.61 5.67-23a9.33 9.33 0 0 1 2.25-1c7.46-2.02 16 5.38 19.08 16.56z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M124.84 85.13l5.3 6.38a31.52 31.52 0 0 1-10.26-2.11 11 11 0 0 0 4.96-4.27z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M127.55 69.88c.81 6-.24 11.49-2.71 15.25l-24.33-29.27c1.55-3.32 4-5.71 7.12-6.58l.66-.16c7.3-1.45 15.43 5.84 18.42 16.69a31.51 31.51 0 0 1 .84 4.06z"/><path class="cls-9" d="M100.51 55.86l24.33 29.27a11 11 0 0 1-5 4.27 8.27 8.27 0 0 1-1.09.38c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-1.79-6.48-1.34-12.81.79-17.39z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M119.88 89.4a31.52 31.52 0 0 0 10.26 2.13 28.08 28.08 0 0 1-10.26 14.78 27.86 27.86 0 0 1-16.66 5.5L79.04 69.53a28 28 0 0 1 21.46-13.67c-2.13 4.58-2.58 10.91-.79 17.39 3.08 11.18 11.62 18.58 19.08 16.53a8.27 8.27 0 0 0 1.09-.38zM79.04 69.53l24.17 42.27a28 28 0 0 1-24.17-42.27z"/><path class="cls-8" d="M103.21 111.8s-22.55 1.78-42.87-5.51 18.7-36.76 18.7-36.76a28 28 0 0 0 24.17 42.27z"/><path class="cls-7" d="M79.04 69.53s-39 29.47-18.71 36.76 42.88 5.51 42.88 5.51M119.88 106.29a28.08 28.08 0 0 0 10.26-14.76M100.5 55.86a28 28 0 1 0 19.36 50.44M119.88 89.4a31.52 31.52 0 0 0 10.26 2.13h2.76a30.58 30.58 0 0 0 23.22-11.82M108.29 49.12a30.85 30.85 0 0 1 22.23-10.59 32.18 32.18 0 0 1 11.86 1.67M119.88 106.29"/><path class="cls-7" d="M127.55 69.88c.81 6-.24 11.49-2.71 15.25a11 11 0 0 1-5 4.27 8.27 8.27 0 0 1-1.09.38c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-1.79-6.48-1.34-12.81.79-17.39 1.55-3.32 4-5.71 7.12-6.58l.66-.16c7.3-1.45 15.43 5.84 18.42 16.69a31.51 31.51 0 0 1 .84 4.06M142.38 40.23a9.33 9.33 0 0 1 2.25-1c7.46-2 16 5.35 19.08 16.53 3 11-.37 21.59-7.59 23.87l-.33.1c-7.46 2-16-5.35-19.08-16.53-2.75-9.93-.21-19.56 5.67-22.97zM127.55 69.88"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="121.08" cy="97.99" r="1.21"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="121.68" cy="94.89" r=".61"/><circle class="cls-10" cx="123.98" cy="95.89" r=".39"/></g><g id="nose"><path class="cls-12" d="M158.21 88.14s-15-7.48-14.14-8.46-1.66 1.52-1.66 1.52c4 .33 11.67 12.18 11.67 12.18"/><ellipse class="cls-13" cx="292.91" cy="122.23" rx="3.34" ry="1.89" transform="rotate(-51.71 192.082 247.63)"/></g><g id="shadows"><path class="cls-14" d="M119.88 89.4s-34.89-1.12-38.22 12.32c0 0 12.9 17.58 37.35 5.2 0 0 10.56-9.67 11.13-15.4 0 .01-10.93-.87-10.26-2.12z"/><path class="cls-14" d="M81.66 101.72s-31.43 1.67-21.34 4.57 32.93 7.11 37 5.51c-.01 0-15.29-6.73-15.66-10.08z"/></g><g id="lights"><path class="cls-16" d="M128.98 38.85s-15 1-20.69 10.27c0 0 15.28-10.05 20.69-10.27zM100.5 55.86S83.77 57.3 76.21 76.04c0 0 13.58-16.85 24.29-20.18zM78.58 69.88S57.78 87 56.14 93.53"/></g><g id="hair"><path class="cls-17" d="M134.75 117.27l1.01-3.74M133.46 113.53l-3.32-1.54M131.85 108.87l1.61-2.58"/><path class="cls-18" d="M112.68 119.71l.53-2.44M107.12 117.27h3.09v-3.74M127.55 115.4h-2.21M126.45 110.67l1.1-3.09M99.27 124.01l1.65-2.27M94.49 119.71h2.83M96.94 117.27l2.33-1.87"/><path class="cls-19" d="M113.32 36.79c9.36-2.93 13.12 8.68 13.12 8.68M127 42.55l-.55-6.85"/></g><g id="eyes"><ellipse cx="253.34" cy="111.51" rx="8.43" ry="10.34" transform="rotate(-22.59 106.112 438.183)"/><ellipse cx="290.34" cy="101" rx="8.43" ry="10.34" transform="rotate(-22.59 143.093 427.685)"/><ellipse class="cls-20" cx="256.2" cy="105.15" rx="1.31" ry="2.26" transform="rotate(-45 149.82 254.532)"/><ellipse class="cls-20" cx="293.63" cy="94.75" rx="1.31" ry="2.26" transform="rotate(-45 187.25 244.128)"/><circle class="cls-20" cx="118.24" cy="75.68" r=".4"/><circle class="cls-20" cx="156.12" cy="65.55" r=".4"/></g></g></svg>

<div id="text">
  <h1> ouch </h1>
</div>
  
</div>
```